# How to translate strings available in JS library?

Tags: javascript, i18n-l10n

I'm showing some images on my site where those are displayed using [jquery.magnific-popup.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js) library. I'm not able to translate a string in that library. i.e.

> "%curr% of %total%"

It is not searchable even in the translate interface. How can I translate it?

[image]

Comment: Drupal doesn't know about strings in 3rd party javascript code (it's client side, and not Drupal), so it won't be able to list them as available translations. I imagine you'll need to implement something yourself with whatever method the library in question provides for localisation. After you've got that bit done you can probably find a way to introduce the new strings to Drupal's translation interface, but I would've thought you'll need to write the integration part first

Answer (score 1):

See the plugin's [translation documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#translating) for a list of strings and their option names.
Pass these strings through [Drupal.t()](https://www.drupal.org/node/323109) when attaching your popup.

Answer (score -1):

Do not waste your time with the interface translation, you may find strings started with "" in jquery.magnific-popup.min.js file, just locate there with your editor, and change them. Just before make a backup of the javascript file for sure.
Then clear your site's cache /admin/config/development/performance and reload your page.
Hope it can help, that's worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it is not recommended to make changes in original files like these, isn't it?